# Hashset is called "hash" set?

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, set, hashset

I know `HashSet` is the implementation of the `Set` interface, but I have a problem understanding the "hash". It seems to work the same as a `Set`, but why it is called "hash"?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to implement a Set interface. `HashSet` is one of them. It uses an underlying `HashMap` to store the elements of the Set. The "hash" part refers to the `hashCode` used to map each element to an index of an array, to allow efficient lookup.

Comment: so in the underlying hashmap the key is the value and the value part is the index of the array or key is the index of the array and the value part is the value?

Comment: @sevenxuguang The element of the HashSet is the key in the underlying HashMap. The value is just a dummy object. The index of the array is calculated as a function of the element's `hashCode`.